# Tkinter no abre mi imagen

Tags: python, tkinter, imagen

Estoy haciendo un programa con tkinter que cada vez que se seleccione una opción despliegue una segunda ventana para hacer funcionar algún objeto. Estas ventanas deben tener imágenes, pero por alguna razón no se abren dichas imágenes aunque python no marca ningún error. Por ejemplo al activar esta función debería de abrirse una ventana con la etiqueta de relevador y una imagen guardada, pero no se abre la imagen. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

````
    Relevador = Toplevel(master)
    Relevador.title("Relevador")
    Relevador.geometry("380x200")
    Label(Relevador, text = "Relevador").pack(pady=10)
    Button(Relevador, text = "Cerrar", command=Relevador.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    Button(Relevador, text = "INICIAR", command= lambda: LlamarRele(Relevador)).place(x=5,y=5)
    fotoultras="Rele.jpeg"
    mi_gif=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fotoultras))
    etiqueta_2=Label(Relevador, image=mi_gif).pack(side=RIGHT)```
````

Comment: Estás creando la imagen dentro de una función?

Comment: No, las últimas tres líneas son la inserción de la imagen, no se crea nada

Comment: Perdón, me refiero a si la estás abriendo dentro de la función.